# How to manage partly incompatible package versions for Python?

Tags: python, package, versions

On my search for a modern programming language I found Python and immediately fell in love with it. However, there are some issues and for me the worst is Python version combined with packages.

I started using Python 3.3 and soon found that version numbers are increasing comparatively quickly. Trying some new ones (3.4.3, 3.50b1 and 32bit 3.50b3) I also realized that packages are not necessarily compatible after an upgrade. Meanwhile I am pretty confused and switch back and forth between different versions depending on my needs.

I mainly need to

1. import data from **excel files** (csv and text files are no problem) and
2. apply **numerical methods** on that data.

Therefore I would like to use **openpyxl**, **numpy**, or **pandas** as an alternative for both.

For coding I use **iep** and **PyCharm** on a **64 bit Windows 7**. Numpy turned out to be tricky on Win7, but I could install it for Python 3.4.3. It also shows up in PyCharms package list for one of the 32 bit 3.5, but it does not work (some dll missing). Openpyxl instead only works on 3.5, so **I cannot use openpyxl and numpy at the same time**.

Do you experience such problems too (according to search engines, such issues seem to be common, working solutions seem to be less frequent)? If yes, is there a way how to deal with that properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python world to separate package versions for different projects tools like "[pyvenv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)" and "[virtualenv](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)" are usually used.

Also "conda" environments are used, but less common. Though for data processing one thing suggested is "Anaconda", see https://www.continuum.io/downloads.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11149854)

Comment: Why doesn't this answer the question?  This would be an excellent use case: to add some more details.  What I would suggest is 
A) Create a virtual environment with openpyxl (which I assume handles reading data from excel) and write a script that converts it from excel to CSV 
B) Create a virtual environment with numpy and pandas which is set to use python 3.4.3 ... this can read in the outputs from A as CSV ... yes, it's a bit more of a pain to have to switch between virtual environments but it beats having to setup crazy IPC type stuff

Comment: You should put this in your answer, not the comments, right?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11149854)

Comment: @Trilarion, the question is "Do you experience such problems too (according to search engines, such issues seem to be common, working solutions seem to be less frequent)? If yes, is there a way how to deal with that properly?". I might forget to answer the first part, then here it is: "I used to experience similar problems, before I started to use virtualenv, and no pyvenv". The second part is in my answer with links to official documentation.

Comment: @NJ Nilesh J, the answer provides a way to solve the problem and the links lead to official documentation. IMO, copying the tool usage from documentation is redundant in this case.

Comment: @defferl, Added a link to "Anaconda", that might interest you.

Comment: @all Thanks very much for the help, as I am quite new to Python I also appreciate comments which deviate a little from my original question (although it is not clear whether that really took place here...). So it really looks as if such problems are not unique and that there are tools to handle that. I'll certainly try them. And Anaconda looks very interesting too! Having all the packages without bothering sounds great :)